# Isochoric heating of a mixture of ideal gases with different heat capacities

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I was thinking about the following situation:

Suppose we have an equimolar mixture of 1 mol argon gas (C=1.5 R) and 1 mol of nitrogen (C=2.5 R) and we heat it isochorically with 10 kJ from room temperature.

How can one calculate the final temperature then? I know we need to use the relation dU=C*dT, because the heat energy is converted to internal energy, but also argon should heat more quickly than nitrogen.

Does one need to use just the average of the heat capacity (2R) to calculate the temperature change or how can we do it? I couldn’t find practice problems with a similar question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that in the case of gaseous mixtures, particular gases are not being heated separately as macroscopic entities, all is done on the molecular level. It does not matter how much of thermal energy a particular molecule of either of gases obtains during heat conduction. As this energy is extremely quickly (locally) evenly redistributed across all respective degrees of freedom by mutual collisions with the typical collision rate $\pu{E10 s−1}$). This still allows the macroscopic temperature gradient.

---

Work with the system heat capacity

$$C_\mathrm{V,sys} = n_1 \cdot C_\mathrm{1,V,mol} + n_2 \cdot C_\mathrm{2,V,mol}.$$

Then $$q = C_\mathrm{V,sys} \Delta T$$

---

The alternative approach is to formally use the effective molar heat capacity as the weighted average of molar heat capacities of involved gases:

$$C_\mathrm{V,sys, mol} = \frac{n_1 \cdot C_\mathrm{1,V,mol} + n_2 \cdot C_\mathrm{2,V,mol}}{n_1+n_2},$$

and then to use the molar amount of mixture molecules, regardless of the molecule types:

$$q = n_\mathrm{mix} \cdot C_\mathrm{V,sys,mol} \cdot \Delta T$$

---

Note that, generally, there is nonzero heat of mixing, as ChetMiller correctly pointed out.  But, for gaseous mixtures like $\ce{Ar}$ + $\ce{N2}$, at usual conditions, is this deviation negligible.  The heat of mixing is an issue rather for calorimetry in evaluation of heat capacities of mixed condensed phases.

There is more important effect of the temperature dependency of molar heat capacities of polyatomic gases, as quantized vibration modes become more active in higher temperatures.

Wikipedia, [molar heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity) of chosen gases as function of temperature:

> [image: Wikipedia, molar heat capacity of chosen gases as f(T)]

Comment: Ah so it’s easier than expected, just sum the molar weighted heat capacities and calculate dT.

Comment: Q=CvDeltaT;  deltaT = Q/Cv ;  Cv is the weighted average by moles.

Comment: @jimchmst Does it mean the average we are using here is not actually the algebraic average but instead average by moles? I think this makes the difference.

Comment: @Proscionexium It is called a weighted average, where the weights are here molar fractions.

Comment: This applies only to an ideal gas mixture, where the heat of mixing is known to be zero.

Comment: Sure, but I thought a caveat would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Added mixing notes to the answer.